# Get avalue from json list from API response in postman

Tags: json, postman

Need to get Value of Id for DisplayName": "Samsung XCover 4 from API response
I tried this but not working.

```
    var response = JSON.parse(responseBody);
    {
    var count = Object.keys(response.Offerings[0]);
    console.log(count);
    for(var x =0; x <=count.length ; x++)
    { 
    if(count[x] == 'Id')
    {
    var val =   
    console.log(response.Offerings[0].count[x]);
    // console.log(pm.environment.get(count['Id']));
    }
    }
    }
```

Response from API:

```
   {
   "Offerings": [
    {
            "Amount": 292,
            "CurrencyCode": "CAD",
            "DisplayName": "Samsung XCover 4",
            "Id": 1910256761716000500,
            "Language": "en-CA",
            "LineOfBusinesses": [
                10048
            ],
            "MarketingViews": [],
            "Name": "Samsung XCover 4",
            "OfferType": 1,
            "ShortDescription": "Offering bundle includes:\n- Airtime Product\n- Samsung XCover 4 device\n- SIM Card\n- & optional device protection",
```

I have a log list of DisplayName & Id but i need to use the Id for "DisplayName": "Samsung XCover 4" in body of other API.

Comment: * I have a long list of DisplayName & Id but i need to use the Id for "DisplayName": "Samsung XCover 4" in body of other API.

Answer (score 0):

var response = JSON.parse(responseBody); for(var i=0; i<=response.Offerings.length ; i++) { if(response.Offerings[i].DisplayName == 'Samsung Galaxy S9+') { console.log(response.Offerings[i].Id); } }
I am getting Is as 1910256760591000600 but it's automatically round off.

Is there any way to stop the rounding off and get the exact Id from response?

Answer (score 0):

I have used eval(globals.bigint_fix); on tests and set global variable bigint_fix value as bigint.js script.

Comment: Worked for me also. Thanks